# Can't use glut functions after including glew c++

Tags: c++, glut, glew

I use glut to create a basic openGL program. Everything worked fine until I included glew as well.
Now the compiler can't find the glut functions.

I'm including them in this order:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Using GL/gl.h instead of glew works but then I can't use the openGL extensions.

The compiler outputs `undefined reference` for every glut and gl function like `glutInit`, `glBegin`. I can't find any glut related .lib files on my hdd but for some reason it works when I don't include glew. I already copied the glew files to the right directories. (glew32.lib, glew32mx.lib, glew32mxs.lib and glew32s.lib to mingw/lib, wglew.h, glxew.h, glew.h to mingw/include/GL and glew32.dll, glew32mx.dll to mingw/bin and windows/system32)

The compiler arguments are `-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL  -lglut32 -lglew32 -lglu32 -lwinmm -lgdi32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop using old GLUT; use FreeGLUT instead.

Second, you *still* need to link to OpenGL32 if you want to use OpenGL.

Comment: @relgukxilef: please mark this as the answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: @ViteFalcon sorry. I wanted but Stack Overflow said I had to wait.